# UIWebView is blank during download

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I am trying to load a UIWebView with a website that downloads 99% of the data but takes forever to finish. When this happens the UIWebView is empty until it finally does, Safari displays it instantly but still shows it's downloading for another 3 minutes. How do I make a UIWebView display as it's downloading?

Answer (score 1):

This [bit of code](http://www.programbles.com/2010/03/23/simple-way-to-control-the-initial-appearance-of-a-uiwebview/) is the only thing I can really find.  It won't let you preload the page, but it will let you put something there instead of a blank screen.